# How do question migration paths get set up?

Tags: support, migration

When you vote to close a question, a list of related candidates to move the question to shows up. For us this is only Meta.Rpg.

How does this list come to be? Is it strictly manual?

If it's manual, could we get BoardGames.SE and/or Gaming.SE added?

The question that brings this up is this one: [Which game system was the computer game Hero-Quest based on?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6391/which-game-system-was-the-computer-game-hero-quest-based-on)

It's a fair question, but as the answer indicates it isn't actually about RPGs. I'd like to see it moved to a more appropriate SE, but I only have the option to vote to close or ask a mod to step in... And I'm not sure it's worth bothering the mods about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no migration paths for beta sites besides their own meta.  However, mods can migrate to any site, so if you really think migration is needed for a particular post then flag it for their attention.